# Chapter name in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I need the authors to be written in the table of contents before the chapter name. Moreover, the names of the authors are written in bold, and the chapter name in italics as in the photo.[image: simple]

MWE:

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}        % нежирные номера страниц у глав в оглавлении
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}% нежирные точки до номеров страниц у глав в оглавлении
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\textsf}                       % нежирные названия глав в оглавлении
\cftpagenumbersoff{part} % убираем номер страницы для части
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\textsf\large\bfseries}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand{\PartTitle}{{Part Title}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\PartTitle}

\renewcommand{\firstchapter}{\{First Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\firstchapter}
\renewcommand{\secondchapter}{\{Second Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\secondchapter}
\renewcommand{\thirdchapter}{\{Third Chapter title}} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thirdchapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete your MWE down to `\end{document}`. In particular include a couple of chapters.